# Is there any way not to make so many queries to the database?

Tags: c#, dapper

In c# I have a list of art_id, for example 10000 elements.

And I make something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; list.Count; i++)
{
  list[i].someValue = SQL.QueryOne("select ... where p.art_id = list[i].art_id);
}
```

And it's so slow, is any way to do it better? AND WORKING FASTER. My project using Dapper, and the database is Oracle 19c.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a list of ids in one query, using IN

```
var ids = list.select(x=>x.someValue);

"select p.art_id, ... where p.art_id IN (@ids)"
```

that should return the ids found along with their related data, and then you can enumerate that into list[i].someValue.

Amongst the caveats would be that for large numbers of ids, they should be split into a small number of queries (e.g. perhaps one query per 1000 ids).   Measure what that number should be.